# Running a set of data through multiple calculations and outputting the results back on the data sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2013

Using Microsoft Excel 2013.

I am creating a calculation sheet for quickly evaluating the metrics of rental properties.  I have a sheet called `CALCULATIONS` with several calculations, and several inputs - all having to do with a single property.  In the end, I get a few outputs (profit, ROI, etc...). All on the same sheet.

I also have a sheet called `DATA` which contains several columns of data (these are the inputs to the sheet `CALCULATIONS`.  The `DATA` sheet has many rows, every property I am interested in, I manually write the data in each column for the property.  Consider this my database.

Basically, I want to calculate the outputs to the `CALCULATIONS` sheet, based on each row of inputs from the `DATA` sheet.  I often change data on the DATA sheet, and want to re-run this each time to see the new outputs in one place - on the DATA sheet.

How can I accomplish this?  I assume macro's are the way to do it, but unfortunately with no luck finding a similar problem on google I am here asking for some further clarifications and help.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. For each property, you have one row on `CALCULATIONS` and one row on `DATA` (or even _n_ rows on `CALCULATIONS` and _m_ rows on `DATA`), and the `CALCULATIONS` sheet contains formulas that use values on `DATA`? What's the issue? Does the `CALCULATIONS` sheet fail to update when you change values on `DATA`?

Comment: I may have been unclear.  I just commented in the answer below as well - but there are some large amortization tables depending on different inputs for each row (to calculate mortgage payments, for example).  Similarly I escalate rent costs and other costs each year by a different amount depending on the property.  So I can't do row-to-row calcs like that unfortunately.    The same tables and formulas need to be used for each row.  I currently use OFFSET() to quickly bring in the inputs, but it still causes a lot of manual interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of feeding each property to the calculation sheet individually (and then writing the calculation results back to the data sheet), you may want to consider building the calculation in VBA, using UDFs. Then you can use these user-defined-functions in every row in the data sheet.

Also, are you sure that you require a calculation sheet to arrive at the result? Maybe the calculation sheet can be turned into individual formulas right in the data sheet.

Edit after the clarifying comment:

You need a macro that

- runs a loop on all rows in the DATA sheet that does the following for each row:
- copies the pertinent cells of the current row into the CALCULATIONS sheet
- ensures the calculations are refreshed
- copies the pertinent cells from the calculation sheet into the current row of the DATA sheet
- repeats the same actions for the next row in the DATA sheet.

In order to get a handle on the code required to do that, you can start with letting the macro recorder track the actions you use to copy the data from one row in the data sheet to the calculations sheet, recalculate and then copy the results back into the data sheet.

How much more help you need depends on your VBA skills. I suggest that you break this down into several questions, tackling one issue at a time. It would also help immensely to know more about the data structure of your file, so sharing a file via a file sharing service might be an idea.

Comment: In this case, there is a large amortization table, along with a few other "repetitive" calcs for "each month" calculations and "each year" calculations, so unfortunately I don't think there is an easy way to do it otherwise...

Comment: I edited my answer with an approach for VBA